# Laravel completely ignoring routes.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, bitnami

I'm using Laravel to create a simple company website. I defined a basic route that should represent my homepage as follows:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', 'IndexController@index');
```

This is my index controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class IndexController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return View::make('index');
    }
```

I have ommited the other methods as they haven't been changed after doing php artisan make:controller.

I'm using Bitnami WAPP stack currently. I already have a working second application that I can correctly use(not ignoring its routes.php file).
I put this application in a folder in /htdocs.

I start the app by using cmd on Windows to navigate to the folder and then do php artisan serve. When I type in localhost:8000, index.php is loaded, but not through my controller. I tested this by typing die() in the controller method before returning the view(the view is placed in resources/views as index.blade.php). I even tried to echo something from routes.php with no results.

The problem therefore is that the server loads the page, but not through my controller but just serving a file whose name is index.php.

Please, if you need any more info tell me, this is driving me nuts.

Comment: I presume that you are using Laravel 5. Could you please try ````die()```` inside the ````web/index.php```` file within your project's root directory?

Comment: @Praveesh Where is the web directory located(I can't find it on project root)?

Comment: Extremely sorry look in the ````public```` directory. For a moment I was thinking the Symfony way.

Comment: I tried using <?php die(); ?> in public/index.php after which a white screen is shown(no html is loaded because I put die() at the beginning). When I remove it the page is shown again.

Comment: @Praveesh any ideas?

Comment: What are the contents of the ````index.php```` file that gets rendered?

Comment: @Praveesh it contains only html.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87473/discussion-between-praveesh-and-matsura).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did here was accidentaly delete the index.php file thinking I wrote it when it was actually laravels file. Stupid mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Your route is cached. Clear the cache and should work. I faced the same problem.

```
php artisan route:clear
```